# swift sorting an array of objects

Tags: swift

I've an array of objects with one date field of type string. This is field represents 'UTC' date string. I'm not able to figure out a way to sort this array on the date field in swift 3.0.

Example:

```
 class Item {
   var name: String
   var type: String
   var dateAdded: String   //This contains UTC date string 
   init(name:String, type: String, dateAdded: String) {
      self.name = name
      self.type = type
      self.dateAdded = dateAdded
   }
}


var itemArray:[Item];
var item1 = Item(name: "Name1", type: "Person", dateAdded: "2018-03-05T13:15:30Z")
var item2 = Item(name: "Name2", type: "Animal", dateAdded: "2018-03-04T10:15:30Z")
itemArray.append(item1)
itemArray.append(item2)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The code doesn't compile

Comment: I'm sorry for missing the existing question. BTW, code above is a snapshot with few more things.